# Build Process in TFS 2010

Tags: build-process, build-automation

I have read articles on build automation and it looks simple, but I am really not sure about parameterized build. I believe, there must be a xml file for that.

When we say build is automated, I believe it means our code/binaries sit in test environemnt. And all application related settings will also configured just by simple clicks of build, and push.

What are the required tools? What is MSBuild ?

Please put some light on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSBuild is and exe that you run with command line tools and pass to it the project file (.csproj) which is an XML file as you said and it has all the instructions needed as you configured.

I created a series of videos that describe how to create simple MSBuild tasks and how to organize tasks and so on, for more info click on the following link:

[MSBuild Tutorial](http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/msbuild-tutorial/)

- **MSBuild is exe**

[image]

- **When you run MSBuild from Command line**

[image]

- **You will need to unload the projct so you can edit the (.csproj) or    project file**

[image]

- **The (.csproj) or project file**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about build automation, and by your tags you menation TFS 2010 if so then you only need a cursory understanding of msbuild to get started. It is what eventually calls the compiler, but in all hoensty you need the step above it which are the build templates and defintions, along with how to set up agents and controller.

[Here](http://www.woodwardweb.com/talks/tsugve/TeamBuild2010.pdf) is a good overview document by Martin Woodward, this should give you enough to figure things out, or ask more specific questions